# How to make a link show after a certain amount of clicks on a word?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am a beginner to javascript. I have a function where you click on a word and a series of other words follows after every time you click on the first word. I would like for a link to show once all the words in the string are shown (from clicking on the word exactly 25 times). I can't seem to figure out how to get the link to show after the word is clicked.

here is my code.

```
<div id="container"> 
    <span onclick="bla();">click on this sentence to show the string of  words</span>
    <div id="words"></div>
</div>

<script>
    var k = 0;

    function bla() {
        var ph = ["word1", "word2", "word3", "word4", "word5","word6", 
            "word7","word8",  "word9", "word10",  
            "word11","word12","word13","14","15","16",
            "17","18","19",
            "20","21","22","23", "24","25" ];
        var container = document.getElementById('words');
        var count = container.length - 25;

        if (k < ph.length) {
            var word = document.createTextNode(ph[k] + ' ');
            container.appendChild(word);
            k++;
        }
    }

    function bla() {
        if (container.length == count) {
            con.appendChild(text1);
            $(text1).fadeIn(500);    
        } 
    }

    var text1 =document.createElement('div');
    text1.innerHTML = '<a href="nightsky.html">
        a few million years in space
        is like, how many years on earth?';

    text1.style.padding ="20px";
    text1.style.display ="none";

    container.addEventListener('click', bla);
    bla();

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm trying to learn more about this and any advice or explanation would be very appreciated! thank you so much.

Comment: Why do you have two functions called `bla`?

Comment: 1. You have the same function name twice (bla), 2. Javascript do not have multiline strings (not one that should be used anyway), 3. Since you have the same name twice, which function do you think it will run? 4. What is variable `con` ?

Comment: ah, i just don't really know what i'm doing. I got that code from someone who said they could help me, and I don't know what to do with it to make it work. I don't know what variable con is and I'm not sure what function will run. help? ugh i'm sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Well, we where all beginners at one time.

I refactored your code, since it wasn't working the way it was written.

```js
var e = { }; // Global variable for elements
var currentWord = -1; // Global variable indicating current word. (-1 = before first word)
// Global variable with words
var myWords =[
  "word1", "word2", "word3", "word4", "word5",
  "word6", "word7", "word8", "word9", "word10",
  "word11", "word12", "word13", "word14", "word15",
  "word16", "word17", "word18", "word19", "word20",
  "word21", "word22", "word23", "word24", "word25"
];
//function that adds the text after all words has been shown
function addText() {
  var text1 =document.createElement('div');
  var link = document.createElement('a');
  link.href = 'nightsky.html';
  link.textContent = 'a few million years in space  is like, how many years on earth?';
  text1.appendChild(link);
  text1.style.padding ="20px";
  e.container.appendChild(text1);
}

function update() {
  // First we must add one to the currentWord variable. There are
  // a couple of ways to do that:
  // pre-increment:  ++currentWord;
  // post-increment:  currentWord++;
  // assignment operator: currentWord += 1;
  // calculate and assign : currentWord = currentWord + 1;
  currentWord += 1;

  // Check if all words has been shown
  if (currentWord < myWords.length) {
    // Show next word
    var word = document.createTextNode( myWords[currentWord] + ' ' );
    e.words.appendChild(word);
  } else {
    // Add text
    // Only add the text is currentWord is identical to myWords.length
    if ( currentWord == myWords.length) addText();
  }
}

function loaded() {
  // Get relevant elements and store them in the variable e
  e.container = document.getElementById('container');
  e.words = document.getElementById('words');
  e.hot = document.getElementById('hot');
  // Add the click-handler to the hot element
  e.hot.addEventListener('click',update);
}

loaded(); // Should be called 'onload' or DOM-ready
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <span id="hot">click on this sentence to show the string of words</span>
  <div id="words"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please feel free to ask about anything in the code above that you don't understand. I have deliberately not used any jQuery.

Comment: I'm happy that you liked it! Do you understand every bit of the code? By the way, if you found this answer to be the most useful of your question, you should accept it :)